# Typo3 Translation in Inline Viewhelper

Tags: templates, typo3, fluid, viewhelper

I want to set a translation for my Typo3 template.
But I want a translation with `{f:translate ...}` of a string within a inline viewhelper like this.

```
{f:if(condition:"{change.newValue}", then : '{change.newValue}', else:
"{f:translate (key:'pdvcalls_form_fields.deleted_close_date')}")}
```

But this is not working. 
Has anyone a idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra space before the function paratheses.

```
{f:if(condition:"{change.newValue}", then : '{change.newValue}', else:
"{f:translate(key:'pdvcalls_form_fields.deleted_close_date')}")}
```